# Change install path for python package when creating .deb-package

Tags: python, package, distutils, deb

I'm trying to create a deb-package from distribution in a tarball. It has `setup.py` file.
My actions are:

```
python setup.py --command-packages=stdeb.command sdist_dsc
cd deb_dist/<pkgname>
debuild -uc -us -i -b
```

Everything works fine. But when i do

```
dpkg -i <pkgname>.deb
```

all package module's files are installs into `/usr/share/pyshared/<pkgname>` directory and i want to change it.

Is it possible? How?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

That's the right directory for installation of Python system libraries, according to [Debian Python Policy](http://www.debian.org/doc/packaging-manuals/python-policy/). The generated deb source ought to be arranging for those files to be symlinked into the appropriate `/usr/lib/python2.*/dist-packages` directories, based on what Python versions are installed. That would be normally be taken care of by the `dh_python2` tool during package build; it should put calls to `update-python-modules` in the generated postinst.

That behavior can be changed, but the right way to change it depends on the reason you want to change it. What part of this process isn't working for you?